# Customize the "about" widget in hugo academic theme

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown

I am using the hugo-academic theme via RStudio/blogdown to build my webpage. The example page is here: https://themes.gohugo.io/theme/academic/

I would like to add a second list of non-academic **Interests** below the academic ones. Is this possible?

In the configuration section of `about.md` there is a section for this list

```
# List your academic interests.
 [interests]
   interests = [
     "Artificial Intelligence",
     "Computational Linguistics",
     "Information Retrieval"
   ]
```

but i am not sure how it is passed to the process that actually builds the site. In the spirit of "just add stuff to see if it works" i've tried adding another [other_interests] section but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 6):

You can add another list of interests, but the theme doesn't know about the list you added. In the theme's source you'll find this section:

```
  {{ with $page.Params.interests }}
  <div class="col-sm-5">
    <h3>{{ i18n "interests" | markdownify }}</h3>
    <ul class="ul-interests">
      {{ range .interests }}
      <li>{{ . }}</li>
      {{ end }}
    </ul>
  </div>
  {{ end }}
```

https://github.com/gcushen/hugo-academic/blob/master/layouts/partials/widgets/about.html#L50-L59

Which renders an HTML section based on a predefined list.
You could try to copy/paste this section and change `interests` to your `other_interests` and see how it goes:

```
  {{ with $page.Params.other_interests }}
  <div class="col-sm-5">
    <h3>{{ i18n "interests" | markdownify }}</h3>
    <ul class="ul-interests">
      {{ range .other_interests }}
      <li>{{ . }}</li>
      {{ end }}
    </ul>
  </div>
  {{ end }}
```

I suggest reading up on [templating in Hugo](https://gohugo.io/templates/introduction/) to get a better understanding of what's happening there. If you have more questions specific to this theme, maybe the [source GitHub repository](https://github.com/gcushen/hugo-academic/issues) might be a good place to start.