# Editing Hugo-Academic theme in `blogdown` doesn't show updates made

Tags: rstudio, hugo, blogdown

I am using `blogdown` for the first time and have installed the `Hugo-academic` theme via the recommended method, `blogdown::new_site(theme = 'gcushen/hugo-academic')`.

I have started editing the `config.toml` and the updates render as expected.  After attempting to edit the `about.md` file it appears that none of the edits I've made are showing up.  I've deleted some of the example files (such as *Selected Projects*, etc) however the site preview still shows them .  I came across ([Customize the "about" widget in hugo academic theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45022765/customize-the-about-widget-in-hugo-academic-theme)) which feels related, and upon executing `hugo -v` in terminal (within RStudio in the same project) I get the following error which I can't comprehend:

```
ERROR 2018/06/25 19:50:10 Error while rendering "home" in "": template: index.html:1:3: executing "index.html" at <partial "widget_page...>: error calling partial: template: partials/widget_page.html:23:9: executing "partials/widget_page.html" at <partial $widget $par...>: error calling partial: template: partials/widgets/projects.html:66:84: executing "partials/widgets/projects.html" at <delimit.Params.tags...>: error calling delimit: can't iterate over <nil>
```

**An attempt at understanding**: Have I deleted a file I should not have or not updated something in `config.toml` such that it is looking for a file which I've now deleted?

I'm on a Mac, and using RStudio version 1.1.453 in case it is useful to know

Answer (score 0):

I will have to see what changes you have made in the config.toml. 
If you scroll down in the config.toml file you should find `[params.menus]` in that the first menu is for About. It looks like this:

```
[[menu.main]]  
  name = "About me"  
  url = "#about"  
  weight = 1
```

If the params are okay, and if you edited the about.md file in the `root>content>home` folder it should be okay.

Comment: I've edited the `config.toml` extensively, and the corresponding `[params.menus]` for customization; the initial item/table now looks like: `[[menu.main]]  name = "Home"  url = "#bio"  weight = 1` -- there also exists a file in the `content/home` directory called `bio.md` which is basically a customized About Me

Comment: for the sake of debugging, why don't you revert to the original config.toml file, and use the edited about.md file. This should help to determine if it is your new config that's breaking the site or the fact that you edited the about.md file. Remember to serve_site again.

Comment: I've been doing this and agree this is probably the best course of action given the number of edits/customization performed -- thanks