# How to change a subtitle in Hugo academic about page

Tags: hugo

I would like to change the subtitle of 'Interests' to 'Aims' on the about page of the the Hugo academic template. I tried to follow [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45022765/customize-the-about-widget-in-hugo-academic-theme) but it simply duplicates an Interests list even though I had renamed it to Aims.

How can I change the subtitle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just changing the label from "Interests" to "Aims", can be done by overwriting the default translation of the theme.

First create a directory named "i18n" in your Hugo root directory.
In this directory you place the new translations. In case of English this file will be named "en.yaml". The file will contain only the *new* translation of the id "interests" (warning: correct indentation is important!)

```
- id: interests
  translation: "Aims"
```